# Native build of gcc compiler on windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compile, gcc

I'd like to make a native build for the gcc compiler on my Windows 7 X64 laptop.  After reading the installation instructions and realizing they were for a Unix system, I decided that it was time to seek help from someone with some more experience.  I don't want to do anything fancy, just pretty much build the compiler in a fairly efficient form for my system.

I've already downloaded the source files and have a basic idea of where I want to install it but don't know how to proceed from there. I know there are pre-built binaries out there but I'd kinda like to make some optimizations specifically for my system.

Comment: Building `gcc` for Windows is not a simple task, primarily because it makes so many assumptions about being built and installed into a unix-like environment that Windows doesn't even come close to providing.  It's why projects like MinGW & MSYS exist -- to provide those foundations and patches just to get the compiler built.  In fact, you'd do well to get very familiar with MinGW & friends first, because the results of your effort are going to end up similar to theirs, and there's no reason to redo their work unless you like reinventing wheels.

Comment: add Cygwin, which can build windows (read: non-cygwin) code, with the appropriate flags and headers.

Comment: @afrazier, so what your saying is I might as well just grab their build since they have already done what I'm attempting to do?  If that's the case, do you have a particular project you'd recommend I get my build from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @afrazier and @Rich Homolka have said in comments to your question, you need [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW & MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/)  to build gcc on windows.

There is at least two projects on sourceforge that provide a build of gcc for developing 64 bit windows applications:

[TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) version 4.6.1 (GCC / MinGW / MinGW-w64 compiler suite for 32- and 64-bit Windows) was built on Windows 7 64-bit using MinGW & MSYS. See the [build notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/Sources/TDM%20Sources/). A single file installer is also available in the "Bundle Installer" section of the [download page](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download).

[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (GCC for both x64 & x86 Windows) has in their SVN repository a [howto](http://mingw-w64.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mingw-w64/trunk/mingw-w64-doc/howto-build/) that describes how to build Mingw-w64 GCC on Cygwin, MinGW & MSYS, and *nix shells.

You can also have a look at the answers of these questions:

- [How to install GCC on Windows7](https://superuser.com/q/195317/116987)
- [how to install cygwin and mingw under windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544296/663518)

Comment: I would opt for MinGW. It is specialized to create native Windows executables that don't need the cygwin1.dll library to work

Comment: Thank you both for the advice, I will start exploring your various suggestions.  Setting up a C compiler on windows seems to be a lot more involved then I anticipated.

Comment: @Cole, installing gcc is much easier than building it from source. For example, TDM-GCC bundle installer provide a C compiler and associated tools in a few mouse clicks.